# Removing chloride ions from humic acid purification

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, purification, separation-techniques

I used HF and HCl in humic acid purification, and now I need to remove the Cl ions from solution. What should I do to remove the Cl ions? Do I just wash it with distilled water, or is there another procedure for this?